# How to achieve a "balanced" min-cost flow solution

Tags: algorithms, network-flow

I'm not too familiar with minimum cost flows, so please bear with me. I need to calculate the minimum cost flow for a network that looks like this:

[image]

(The numbers in parentheses next to nodes indicate supply, and the numbers on the arcs indicate the capacity and cost of that arc.)
There are essentially $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ different solutions to this minimum cost flow.
For a given solution, let $c_F$ (resp. $c_G$) denote the total cost of paths that terminate at the node $F$ (resp. $G$). For example, given this solution:

[image]

we would have $c_F = 1+3 = 4$ and $c_G = 2 +4 = 6$.

Now, out of all valid solutions, I need to choose the one that minimizes $|c_F - c_G|$, i.e. the one that most "balances" the costs to $F$ vs the costs to $G$. Is it possible to modify the network (e.g. by adding additional arcs/nodes) to ensure that this constraint is satisfied after solving using a minimum cost flow algorithm? If not, are there any other approaches to solving this problem?

The more general setting for this problem is for networks of the form

[image]

where $c_i, \ell \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ and $n \geq k$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami No, I also need to minimize the cost of flow. The cost does matter if you look at the general setting.

Comment: The first priority is cost of flow. Then among all solutions with minimal cost, minimize $|c_F - c_G|$.

Comment: No, because if $n > k$ then not every $B_i$ will have a path running through it.

Comment: For every $B_{i}$, do you have an edge to every $C_{j}$?

Comment: Yes. Though I'm also interested in the case where every $B_i$ only connects to a subset of the $C_j$.

Comment: The max-flow is always $\min \{n,k\ell\}$. Is it? In that case, the minimum cost will always be the sum of smallest $t$ $c_{i}$'s for $t = \min \{n,k\ell\}$?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: However for the more more general case where each $B_i$ only connects to a subset of the $C_j$, the max flow will still be $\min\{n, k \ell\}$ but then finding the correct $c_i$'s is more complicated.

Comment: When $B_i$ connects all $C_j$'s, then the solution is trivial right? You have identified the min-cost max flow. Now, you just need to equally distribute the selected $B_{i}$'s among all $C_j$'s

Comment: How do you equally distribute the selected $B_i$? Once you have chosen the $B_i$, it seems that we must find a way to partition the set of corresponding $c_i$ into $k$ subsets of $\ell$ elements (aka choosing which $C_j$ the $B_i$ goes to), such that each partition sums to approximately the same value (i.e. total cost to each $C_i$ is approximately the same). I don't quite see how to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129742/discussion-between-inuyasha-yagami-and-jacob).